# how do I make a limit in up counter?

Tags: objective-c, counter

I am new to Objective-C and I made an up counter. By tapping on a button it will increment by one and made another button to reset to 0 but the problem is I could not make is stop in a spacific number e.g I want it when it reaches 15  reset again to zero

```
-(IBAction)up:(id)sender{
    numbercount = numbercount +1 ;
    counterdisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , numbercount];
}
-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender{
    numbercount = 0 ;
    counterdisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , numbercount];
```

that is my project

Comment: Hint:  Use an `if` statement.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: You should not be attempting to use Objective-C unless you have a reasonable knowledge of C.  That would include knowing how to use an `if` statement.  In fact, you should not be programming at all if you don't understand how to use an `if` statement, as that is the most fundamental control structure is virtually any language.

Comment: Mmmmm I will read about it . Thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the you have the value of your counter stored in a variable, say, `counterValue`.

Every time you add 1 to `counterValue`, simply check if the new value equals 15, and if it does, reset the value back to 0.

```
- (void)buttonTapped {
    counterValue++;
    if(counterValue == 15) {
        counterValue = 0;
    }
}
```

I can't give you a more specific example because you didn't share your current code, so hopefully this is enough to get you started in your own project.

---

Welcome to Stack Overflow!